# is there a way to bind a javafx button to a File property ; if file exists or not enable/disable button

Tags: javafx, javabeans

I there any way to bind a selected File if it exits or not a javaFX button being enabled or disabled? 
I only  see bean properties for strings,etc and not for a File.
I need to enable or disable a button based on whether a File value is valid File or not.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ObjectProperty<File> file = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
BooleanBinding fileExists = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
    file.get() != null && file.get().exists(),
    file);

Button button = new Button("OK");
button.disableProperty().bind(fileExists.not());
```